# Determine if a double value isSafeInteger in C++?

Tags: c++

In JavaScript there is this [isSafeInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger) method. How check the same thing in C++? The most straightforward way would be:

```
bool isSafeInteger(double d) noexcept {
    auto const i = static_cast<std::int64_t>(d);
    return i == d && i <= 9007199254740991 && i >= -9007199254740991;
}
```

But it doesn't feel right. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to check? Are you converting from int64_t to double and back? This is kind of a JS-ism since JavaScript conflates integers and floating point numbers. I'd be suspicious of wanting to check this in C++.

Comment: Also the method you linked is about checking if an _integer_ can be described as a _double_, while in your example you take a _double_ as an argument.

Comment: @ypnos Which numeric_limits constant would you use?

Comment: @ypnos The JavaScript method operates on doubles.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I guess numeric_limits are less helpful after realizing that this is about storing an integer in a double, not the other way round. Regarding JavaScript taking double (because no static typing), the semantic requirement is for the input to be in integer, so why not make it one? If it's too big/small for an integer it will not be safe anyways. But I see the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool isSafeInteger(double d) noexcept {
  if (d>=std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::max()) return false;
  if (d<=std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::min()) return false;
  if (isnan(d)) return false;
  auto as_int=[](double d){return static_cast<std::int64_t>(d);};
  return (as_int(d)==d) && (as_int(d+1)!=as_int(d)) && (as_int(d-1)!=as_int(d));
}
```

this checks it round trips to double, and that adjacent doubles don't round to the same integer, and that the double isn't a NaN (while svoiding triggering any NaN traps).

Finally, guard against out of bounds conversion, which is UB.  We use `>=` and `<=` to be safe due to `+1`/`-1` usage later.

This also works for float, but not for 128 (or 70ish) sized floats.

Comment: Why `static_cast` in one case and C-style cast in two others?

Comment: @ruslan wrote at different times, honestly.  They are both actually static casts.

Comment: @ruskan there rewrote with a lambda, makes line shorter and clearer.

Comment: What is "out of bounds confersion"? Why do you need the `+1`/`-1` part? Why is max value 'not safe'?

Comment: @ayxan converting a double which is outsude of the bounds of possible values of an int is undefined behaviour.  The +- are based in what java requires for its function to return true.